# ImportError: DLL load failed: not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, cython, python-import

I am trying to use Cython to wrap a C++ class. Basically I follow the example at [this page](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html).

I'm using `Windows7 64-bit`, `Python 2.7.4 64-bit`, `MinGW 4.3.3 (32/64bit)`, and the `SDK` has been set to `x64 mode`.

In this case, I successfully build the .pyd file. I tried to import it with following code:

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append("C:\\Rectangle")
 import rect
```

The first two lines work well. When I input the third line, it gave following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import rect
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I compiled the extension in 64bit mode, and every piece of software I used is at least compatible with 64bit. How could such error happened?

May I know how can I work around this?

Many thanks! :-)

Comment: it seems that the problem is that you are compiling with MinGW, you have to commpile using SDK... this is a must in order to make the code work in Windows 7 64-biz. Can you compile other Cython codes in your current software+hardware configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up switching everything to 32bit (python, wxPython, etc.), and everything is fine now.

So, I would really recommend that you use "file rect.pyd" command to determine if your module is really 64bit.

Comment: you can use GNUfile for windows. Once installed then "file rect.pyd" http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm